# React.js - clean way to differentiate loading/empty states in Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my component:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        items: []
    };
},

componentDidMount() {
    // make remote call to fetch `items`
    this.setState({
        items: itemsFromServer
    })
},

render(){
    if(!this.state.items.length){
        // show empty state
    }
    // output items
}
```

Extremely contrived/sandboxed, but this is the general idea. When you first load this component, you see a flash of the "empty state" HTML, as the server hasn't yet returned any data.

Has anyone got an approach/a React Way™ of handling whether there is actually no data vs. showing a loading state?

Comment: The best way to handle this is to make your app isomorphic, that way the html is fully loaded on the page and react intelligently attaches itself. It's definitely not the simplest way though, that would be obscuring your page with a loading spinner and removing it with some JS once the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just been rendering a empty span element but you could just as easily render a CSS spinner of some kind to show it's loading.

```
if(!this.state.items.length){
    return(<div class="spinner-loader">Loading…</div>);
}
```

http://www.css-spinners.com/

You may also want to consider what happens if your response comes back with no results.  I would use (this.state.items === null) to indicate that you are waiting for results and an empty array/collection (!this.state.items.length) to indicate that no results were returned.

Comment: Did you mean to use `this.state.items.length`? `this.state` is an **object** and does not have a `length` property in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.  Updated answer.